# How to make a tye die texture?

Tags: texturing, materials

Does anyone know how to do a texture like this?

[image]

I tried to do with a voronoi texture and overlay it with another voronoi node, but the problem is that the voronoi has always the same distance to each cell. I want the texture to be more dense in some areas and total white in others as it is in this shirt.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way I'd do this is by mixing different noise textures with a Mix RGB node, and using a high contrast noise texture as the fac of the mix RGB node. I'd the add a color ramp at the end to get the colors you want.

The image below is a simple node setup mixing the two noise textures with a high contrast noise texture fac.

[image: SimpleTexture]
[image: SimpleNodes]

The image below is a bit more complicated, but is creates more detail in the texture, and more can be changed and customized.

[image: ComplicatedTexture]
[image: ComplicatedNodes]

This final one is to show how much you can do to modify the texture to your needs.

[image: CrazyTexture]
[image: ScaryNodes]

There is no specific hack to making certain textures. It is mostly just using what you have properly to make what you want. I hope I helped. If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I wonder if I could cause some fractal effect in it. But your answer is good enough already. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple cycles [node group](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/groups.html#node-groups) that you can use for this purpose. The result on a round cube is this:
[image]

The idea is simple, we are mixing two textures, [wave](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/wave.html#wave-texture-node) and [noise](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/noise.html#noise-texture-node) with the base colors of your choosing, using [color ramps](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/color_ramp.html?#color-ramp-node) to add contrast.

[image]
<sup>*Click to enlarge.*</sup>

I have added the .blend as well, feel free to download and play with it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!